# form survey slider which needs jquery code to work correctly

Tags: jquery, forms

I m trying to make a survey where when someone clicks on a radio button the next question slides up and also the button prev and next should show unless the person has click on the radio button this is what i have done so far [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HLvYx/3/)

```
    $("#box input").click(function(){
      $(this).find("div").hide();
    });
```

but i m very new to jquery. and i m having difficulties

help will be much appreciated 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dislick/HLvYx/4/).

If you change your markup a bit, you can use this simple code. It stores the current question number in a variable called `positionQuestions`. It also checks if there are more questions to fadeIn or if you've reached the end.

```
var positionQuestion = 1;
var maxQuestions = $('.question').length;

$('button#next').click(function(){
    if (positionQuestion < maxQuestions)
    {
        positionQuestion++;
        $('.question').fadeOut();
        $('#q' + positionQuestion).fadeIn();
    }
});

$('button#prev').click(function(){
    if (positionQuestion > 1)
    {
        positionQuestion--;
        $('.question').fadeOut();
        $('#q' + positionQuestion).fadeIn();   
    }
});
```